# Launching different robots in Gazebo at the same time

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to write a launch file to simulate two different robots in gazebo at the same time. I've tried many things and changes in my launch file but I can get it working. Sometimes I get two (visual) copies of the same robot. This is part of my launch file

Is the parameter "robot_description" unique or something like that so that just one robot description parameter can be set? Am I missing something? I've tried to include parameters such as:

Also tried to create different groups for each robot ( xxxxxx , and include "-namespace quadrotor" in the spawn node parameters, but nothing.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39371/launching-different-robots-in-gazebo-at-the-same-time/) by [RaulC](https://answers.ros.org/users/2893/raulc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a portion of a launch file I have where I spawn two robots.  I use this format to spawn multiple robots using the same *.urdf or different robots like shown below.

also `roscd gazebo_worlds/launch` and look how the table.urdf.xacro is launched.  I don't think what you have is right.

Hope it helps.

```
<param name="passive_cubelet_1" textfile="/home/andy/ros-fuerte/workspace/Cubelet/urdf/passive.urdf"/> 
<node args="-urdf -param passive_cubelet_1 -x 0.58 -y 0.0 -z 0.585 -R 0.0 -P 0.0 -Y 0.0 -model passive_cubelet_1" name="spawn_passive_cubelet_1" output="screen" pkg="gazebo" respawn="false" type="spawn_model"/>
<param name="inverse_cubelet_2" textfile="/home/andy/ros-fuerte/workspace/Cubelet/urdf/inverse.urdf"/>
<node args="-urdf -param inverse_cubelet_2 -x 0.748 -y 0.0 -z 0.585 -R 0.0 -P 0.0 -Y 0.0 -model inverse_cubelet_2" name="spawn_inverse_cubelet_2" output="\screen" pkg="gazebo" respawn="false" type="spawn_model"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1